# Java search for text in text file

Tags: java, text

I'm trying to create a small Java program that can open programs on command, now, this is a very slow process since it looks through the whole C drive.

Now, I wanted to know, if I were to make it to save the directory it found the program you had it open and write it into a .txt file, how could I make it so that if you ask the program to open the program again it checks if it's in the .txt file first and if it's not it searches through C again.

This is about what I want:

User:    Open notepad
   Program: Opening notepad =starts searching on C:/ for notepad.exe=
   Program: I opened notepad for you! =notepad opens and the directory of notepad.exe is saved in a txt file=

Then later

User:    Open notepad
   Program: Opening notepad =checks the txt file for a directory with notepad.exe in it=

Comment: Why lookup the whole disk? Can't you rely on the PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a key/value pairing system.  There's countless ways to implement that, but if you're running off of a .txt file and parsing it to a String, I would use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

For example, you can set your .txt file up to save in the following syntax:

```
programName:path,anotherProgramName:anotherPath,(etc, etc)
```

Then, after reading the .txt file, call:

```
String string = //your file import;
String[] values = string.split(",");

for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i+){
    String[] currentItem = values[i].split(":");
    if(currentItem[0] == fileNameWeAreLookingFor){
        return currentItem[1];
    }
}
```